# Get Month and Year from textBox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox from which I choose a date. Based on the selection, I have to get the respective month and year and save it as integer in the database. How do I do this?

Comment: Which calender you are using for textbox `asp.net` or `jQuery` datepicker or something else

Comment: Can you please , paste your code , what did you do yet.

Comment: @Pratik, I am using a JQuery date picker.

Comment: @Naresh, I am getting the month and year like so.    Dim nStartMonth =     Month(txtStartDate.Text)
    Dim nStartYear = Year(txtStartDate.Text)

Comment: Perfect. now what is error are you getting while saving it ?
I guess, you are getting right value to your variables.

Comment: @Naresh, I am yet to check. Will let you know in a few minutes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To get the month and year I used the following code.

```
Dim nStartMonth = Month(txtStartDate.Text)

Dim nStartYear = Year(txtStartDate.Text)
```

Thanks all for your time and help! :)

Answer (score 2):

If your are using jquery then add option for dateformat and you will have desired format you want

```
$(function () {
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    }
});
```

});

Here's is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcgupta17/ZnVQy/) for same.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [`DateTimePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xyy1csh.aspx) *****  instead?

However, if you insist on the `TextBox`, use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/f02979c7.aspx) to validate and parse a date. Once you have the `DateTime` you can use it's [`Month`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month.aspx) and [`Year`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year.aspx) properties.

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out dt))
{
    int month = dt.Month;
    int year = dt.Year;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid date");
}
```

*** Edit** since you are using ASP.NET you could use the [`Calendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xyy1csh.aspx) control instead of the `DateTimePicker`. If you're using ASP.NET-Ajax a [`CalendarExtender`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) is also a good alternative.

From the commets i see that you're using VB.NET ....

```
Dim dt As Date
If Date.TryParse(txtDate.Text, dt) Then
    Dim month As Int32 = dt.Month
    Dim year As Int32 = dt.Year
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid date")
End If
```

Comment: I was going to mention that, he asks in asp.net not in windows forms.

Comment: @Tim, I am using a JQuery date picker.

Comment: @Tolga, LOL I am a SHE not a HE anyway.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen: Yes, i saw too late that he's using ASP.NET, but added the ASP.NET alternative in the 5 minute grace period. However, it seems that she wants to parse a text to DateTime anyway. Then the `DateTime.TryParse` is the essential part of the answer.

Comment: @Aishvarya: Since you're using VB.NET i have edited my answer to include it. However, i don't understand why it does matter that you're using jQuery.